# Android 4.4 : SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-fullscreen

I would like to use `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY` mode but i get this error :

**`SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY` cannot be resolved or is not a field**

I don't know where is the problem. Here is an extract of my code :

```
    int uiOptions = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
    int newUiOptions = uiOptions;

    boolean isImmersiveModeEnabled = ((uiOptions | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY) == uiOptions);

    // Navigation bar hiding:  Backwards compatible to ICS.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    }

    // Status bar hiding: Backwards compatible to Jellybean
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
        newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    }

    getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(newUiOptions);
```

And in my manifest :

```
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: What is ^= ?  I have never seen this notation.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky The bitwise ^ operator performs a bitwise exclusive OR operation. ^= means the result is assigned to to the left hand operand.

Comment: Is it the same as: newUiOptions == View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

Comment: View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY flag introduced since API-19 only. So you should write Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 18

Comment: or preferably `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)` instead of `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18)`

Comment: Rather than using XOR - shouldn't you use just a regular OR operator? Otherwise you will be toggling the bits if they already happen to be set.

```newUiOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If this is a compile error, you need to set your build target (e.g., Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse) to API Level 19 or higher.

Comment: i have set mine to minimum of 16 and max of 19 and still get this error message as well

Comment: @Eenvincible: As noted, you need to set your build target. That is not the `minSdkVersion`, nor the `maxSdkVersion` (which you should not be using), or even the `targetSdkVersion`.

Comment: With the mention that I also had to reference a different Android library. That may have been because my .classpath file was read-only, but selecting a different target in the properties had no effect. Going to properties again showed the old target and the project would not compile.

Comment: Remove your older build target api from java build path and then set API LEVEL 19 or higher